# jQuery selection by pattern

Tags: jquery

I have a table of form elements where each row represents a record and column represents a field. I need to select all form elements in a given column.

Form elements in the same column have the same name format. For example, form elements that represent a location would have a name in the format `record*.location`, where `*` is an index.

Is it possible to select them with a single jQuery selection? If so, how does it compare to doing `document.getElementById()` on each one of them in a loop, performance wise?

Comment: what defines which column to you need to get? an event from one of the form elements, or something else?

Comment: any chance of seeing an example of the HTML??? There could be a really simple answer to this one.

Comment: @Stephen The field name is passed as a parameter.

Comment: @Damien Sorry, but I'm not allowed to post it...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use jQuery's custom selector creation, $.expr. I have an example for you at http://jsfiddle.net/ygSAy/

You'll want to limit use of it to specific contexts unless you really work to make the filter function super efficient.

**Edit:** a commented and slightly better performant version: http://jsfiddle.net/ygSAy/2/

Answer (score 4):

```
var locations = $('td :input[name$="\\.location"]')
```

This uses the [`attribute-ends-with-selector`<sup>*(docs)*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-ends-with-selector/) and will select all elements that end with `.location`.

---

Ultimately if you're concerned about performance, you can do your own selection like this:

```
function selectInputs( el, type ) {
    var arr = [],
        inputs = document.getElementById( el ).getElementsByTagName( 'input' ),
        len = inputs.length;
    while( len-- ) {
        if( inputs[len].name.indexOf( type ) > -1 ) {
            arr.push( inputs[len] );
        }
    }
    return arr;
}

var locations = selectInputs( 'myTable', '.location' );
```

You could cache away the DOM selection if elements are not added dynamically. You may want to do that whether or not you use jQuery.

Comment: Thanks, but I need to select all elements with that name pattern, from zero to the last index, say 10, not just a single element,

Comment: @Tom: Ah, I misunderstood. I'll change my answer.

Comment: @Tom: I updated to select all elements that end with `.location`. Is this what you meant? Or did it need to be on a per-row basis?

Comment: Patrick, the only issue here is if he has other things using '.location' at the end of the name. I have no idea if that could be the case, though.

Comment: @patrick dw Thanks again. Do you know by any chance how this compares to the alternative(document.getElementById() in loop) in terms of performance?

Comment: @JAAulde No, that's not the case for me. :)

Comment: @JAAulde: Yes, hard to say without the HTML, but it sounds as though the `.` is used as a separator between the record number and the descriptor. If that's the case, there shouldn't be false positives.

Comment: @Tom: Do the elements have a similar ID attribute? Unless you have an enormous table, I wouldn't worry too much about the difference. We can narrow the selector down a bit if we know they're all `<input>` tags, for example. Ultimately  it will vary by browser.

Comment: Tom, as for your performance question, nothing is faster than straight getElementById(). Even putting it into a loop on a large DOM tree would run faster, as no other selector can run as quickly and jQuery has to loop element collections to find what you're after anyway. That said, there is something to be said for clarity and conciseness of the other selectors. Just make sure you're always working in as specific a context as your situation allows.

Comment: @JAAulde: That's not necessarily true. jQuery uses the native `querySelectorAll` when it's available, which is very fast. I'd bet that a single `getElementsByTagName()` followed by a filter will perform a better in IE than many individual `getElementById` calls.

Comment: @Patrick, you are quite right. I suppose only profiling would tell for sure.